# What is the brick limit in LDD?

Tags: ldd

What is the brick limit for Lego Digital Designer? I got to 12k once, but I usually have it crash at around 9k. Does Lego Corp. have any info on this?

Comment: My system is crashing at 150,000 bricks.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.  What kind of computer?  How much memory?  What is your CPU and OS?

Answer (score 13):

There are no set limits for the quantity of bricks you can place in LEGO Digital Designer. The limit on the amount of pieces you can use is entirely dependent on the specifications of your computer.

You may find performance will be affected not only by the quantity of bricks placed, but the complexity of the geometry used. Metallic and transparent coloured bricks will also require more intense processing to render.

In LDD, under preferences you can also disable high-quality rendering of bricks in the scene view and bricks palette, reduce the complexity of shading, remove brick outlines or increase the compatibility mode to improve the performance.

Consider splitting large models into smaller files and edit them separately. (i.e. a file for each deck of a ship or each building).

Avoid running other applications at the same time as LDD that will take up more resources.

---

### Experiment

Just to test the limits, I reduced the rendering settings completely, and started LDD in compatibility mode. I duplicated a 1x1 tile brick many times, and continued to duplicate them over and over. I managed to have approximately 30,000 bricks saved on my clipboard before it crashed.

I tried again, this time duplicating a stack of 6000 bricks many times, I continued until I reached 100,000 bricks. At this point the program was running very slowly and used up to 861MB of memory, I could have continued but I didn't see any point in doing so.

[image: LDD image with lots of bricks]

Comment: At 25,656 bricks LEGO Digital Designer didn't accept any more grouped pieces from the templates for me. I could add them one by one, but not groups. My PC is a new performance gaming model so that means LDD has a limit or you must have a PC from NASA.

Comment: Hi Alexf, and welcome to bricks. Sadly "new performance gaming" isn't all that descriptive as a PC spec, and as Ambo100's demonstrated, LDD can support 100,000 bricks under some circumstances. We'll admit that 1x1 bricks are probably one of the least resource intensive bricks, but their answer includes tips on what you can do to help in terms of reducing rendering types, colour choices, etc.